# how to use sparse vectors and matrices in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do something very simple, but confused by the abundance of information about sparse matrices and vectors in Python.

I want to create two vectors, x and y, one of length 5 and one of length 6, being sparse. Then I want to set one coordinate in each one of them. Then I want to create a matrix A, sparse, which is 5 x 6 and add to it the outer product between x and y. I then want to do SVD on that A.

Here is what I tried, and it goes wrong in many ways.

```
from scipy import sparse;
import numpy as np;
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssl;

x = sparse.bsr_matrix(np.zeros(5));
x[1] = 1;
y = sparse.bsr_matrix(np.zeros(6));
y[1] = 2;
A = sparse.coo_matrix(5, 6);

A = A + np.outer(x,y.transpose())

svdresult = ssl.svds(A,1);
```

Comment: did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should determine data you want to store in sparse matrix before constructing it. Otherwise you should use [**sparse.csc_matrix**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix) or [**sparse.csr_matrix**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) instead. Then you can assign or change data like this:

`x[0, 1] = 1`

At second, outer product of vectors x and y is equivalent to `x.transpose() * y`.

---

Here is working code:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssl

x = np.zeros(5)
x[1] = 1
x_bsr = sparse.bsr_matrix(x)
y = np.zeros(6)
y[1] = 2
y_bsr = sparse.bsr_matrix(y)

A = sparse.coo_matrix((5, 6)) # Sparse matrix 5 x 6
B = x_bsr.transpose().dot(y_bsr) # Outer product of x and y

svdresult = ssl.svds((A + B), 1)
```

Output:

```
(array([[  5.55111512e-17],
       [ -1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [ -2.77555756e-17],
       [  1.11022302e-16]]), array([ 2.]), array([[ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]))
```